# Erro de Caracteres no Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Não consigo solucionar um erro de caracteres no Visual Studio.

**Código 1:**

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <clocale>
#include <Windows.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    SetConsoleTitle("{ TEST }");
    system("color 0A");

    cout << "Ola Mundo\n";

    cout << "ÁÉÍÓÚÇ\n";

    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Portuguese");
    cout << "ÁÉÍÓÚÇ\n" << endl;

    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    wcout << L"ÁÉÍÓÚÇ" << endl;

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

**Resultado Código 1:**
[image: Print Código 1]

**Código 2:**

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

void SetTitle_lithe() {

    SetConsoleTitle("Process Memory Tools C++ - Family { CODE BUILDING }");
    system("color 0A");

    printf("\n");
    printf("       ██████╗ ██████╗ ██████╗ ███████╗    ██████╗ ██╗   ██╗██╗██╗     ██████╗ ██╗███╗   ██╗ ██████╗ \n");
    printf("      ██╔════╝██╔═══██╗██╔══██╗██╔════╝    ██╔══██╗██║   ██║██║██║     ██╔══██╗██║████╗  ██║██╔════╝ \n");
    printf("      ██║     ██║   ██║██║  ██║█████╗      ██████╔╝██║   ██║██║██║     ██║  ██║██║██╔██╗ ██║██║  ███╗\n");
    printf("      ██║     ██║   ██║██║  ██║██╔══╝      ██╔══██╗██║   ██║██║██║     ██║  ██║██║██║╚██╗██║██║   ██║\n");
    printf("      ╚██████╗╚██████╔╝██████╔╝███████╗    ██████╔╝╚██████╔╝██║███████╗██████╔╝██║██║ ╚████║╚██████╔╝\n");
    printf("       ╚═════╝ ╚═════╝ ╚═════╝ ╚══════╝    ╚═════╝  ╚═════╝ ╚═╝╚══════╝╚═════╝ ╚═╝╚═╝  ╚═══╝ ╚═════╝ \n");
    printf("                            Process Memory Tools C++ - Family { CODE BUILDING }\n");
    printf("\n");
}

int main()
{
    SetTitle_lithe();
    printf(" O processo 'Game.exe' não está em execução, abra e tente novamente!");

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

**Resultado Código 2:**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O problema começou ocorrer após eu haver formatado o Windows. Neste momento o Windows 10 se encontra atualizado na versão mais recente assim como também o Visual Studio e o SDK do Windows. Já tentei realizar o downgrade da SDK do Windows 10 mas não obtive sucesso na resolução do problema também.

**Resultado Código 2 - Anterior a Formatação do Windows:**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como resolver este problema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provavelmente as "configurações regionais" de seu Windows não estão em português, e como você está fazendo a chamada de setlocale com parâmetro errado, você não está conseguindo mudar o locale.

Segundo esta página da Microsoft o nome do locale para português é "portuguese-brazilian", e não "Portuguese": https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/language-strings?view=vs-2017

Você pode mostrar o nome do locale após chamar setlocale, como fiz no exemplo abaixo, para verificar se o locale foi mudado.

Além disso, você deve verificar as configurações de seu Windows referente à língua que está sendo utilizada. Dei uma olhada aqui, e achei bem confuso...na verdade não consegui reproduzir seu problema, no meu Windows funciona normalmente, e esta resposta nem é de fato uma resposta, é mais um comentário com sugestões...

```
#include <clocale>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  cout << "*\n";
  cout << "* antes do setlocale Portuguese\n";
  cout << "* Olá Mundo\n";
  cout << "* ÁÉÍÓÚÇ\n";

  // const char* locale = setlocale(LC_ALL, "Portuguese");
  const char* locale = setlocale(LC_ALL, "portuguese-brazilian");
  cout << "* locale is now [" << locale << "]\n";

  cout << "*\n";
  cout << "* após setlocale Portuguese\n";
  cout << "* Olá Mundo\n";
  cout << "* ÁÉÍÓÚÇ\n" << endl;

  locale = setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
  cout << "* locale is now [" << locale << "]\n";

  cout << "* após setlocale \"\"\n";
  cout << "* Olá Mundo\n";
  cout << "* ÁÉÍÓÚÇ" << endl;
  wcout << L"* ÁÉÍÓÚÇ" << endl;

  cout << "* pressione a tecla ENTER para terminar\n";
  getchar();
  return 0;
}
```